# sql query for monthly amount

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pentaho-spoon

I have table like this,

```
SELECT                                  
  payment_id,amount,payment_date             
FROM payment
```

To get the monthly total amount, i wrote query as

```
SELECT
  payment_id
, SUM(amount) AS Total
, MonthName(payment_date) AS Month

FROM payment
```

But I am getting wrong answer in the amount table as all the values are getting added to the same month.

```
payment_id amount payment_date    
1          19.00  May
```

It would be grateful for me if somebody can help me out in this?

Answer (score 1):

First, always include the year with the month -- presumably that is what you intend.

Second, you need a `group by`.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT year(payment_date) as yyyy, monthname(payment_date) as mm,
      SUM(amount) AS Total
FROM payment p
GROUP BY year(payment_date), monthname(payment_date)
ORDER BY MIN(payment_date);
```

I included the `ORDER BY` so you will get the result set in a reasonable order (as opposed to alphabetically by month name).

Note that `payment_id` doesn't make sense in the `GROUP BY`.  It is probably unique on every row in `payment`.  MySQL will put an arbitrary value on each row.  Almost any other database would generate an error if you have `payment_id` in the `SELECT` but not the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: It was really helpful.Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to group your data by month in order to make the sum.

```
SELECT SUM(amount), MONTH(payment_date) FROM payment GROUP BY payment_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  SUM(amount) AS Total,
  MonthName(payment_date) AS Month
FROM payment
GROUP BY MonthName(payment_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have SQL solution, here is a typical PSI (Pentaho-spoon) solution.[image]

Basically, it is the same. However

- It is visual, thus easier to maintain in case you get more complicated query.
- You have no text to type, only mouse click.
- Your input may come from other sources than a single database.
- Your are one click away of a daily (or hourly) run.

Comment: But what have you calculated in calculator part?